checkSelfPermission always negative. Android
Im trying to check - if app has an permission or not, but recive negative result independently of real state of permission - turn it on or off via adb - same result from checkSelfPermission.
My code to check:
private fun checkInstallPermission(): Boolean {
   return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}

so this is always negative, rather if im do adb shell appops ... permission allow
My manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

Target API: 31
Min API: 30
Im tried to access permissions directly or via package name - same result.
Expecting that this method will be true in case of permission requested and granted.
